# How to add blanks between digits (currency) - Oracle format

Tags: sql, oracle, format, oracle-sqldeveloper, format-model

I need to give format to the following number:

1234567.89

as

1 234 567.89

I already tried:

```
select regexp_replace( '1234567.89', '(...)', '\1 ' ) from dual;
```

But its starting from left to right the counting and it's ignoring the decimal dot.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(10000,'99G999D99MI',
           'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''. ''
           NLS_CURRENCY = '' ') "Amount"
           FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This going to run into same issue with format model. you need to add "9"s amd "G"s to support bigger numbers, like `9G999G999D99MI`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
select replace(to_char(1234567.89, '9,999,999,999,999,999.99'), ',', ' ')  x from dual
```

Only in this case, you need to know how big is the biggest number you will have. If lets say, your biggest number is in millions, make **format model** in billions, so it covers either exact number of digits or more